# python create directory from dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

from nested dictionary create directory in python:

```
{1: {'name': 'John', 'age': '27', 'sex': 'Male'},
          2: {'name': 'Marie', 'age': '22', 'sex': 'Female'}}
```

In simple dictionary ;

i just want directoires like,

```
1/name
1/age
1/sex
2/name
2/age
2/sex
```

How to attain it ? using python

Comment: Probably using some code. What did you try and what difficulties did you have?

Answer (score 2):

Simply iterate over the dictionary and the nested dictionary:

```
import pathlib

s = {1: {'name': 'John', 'age': '27', 'sex': 'Male'},
            2: {'name': 'Marie', 'age': '22', 'sex': 'Female'}}

for key, val in s.items():
    if isinstance(val, dict):
        for inner_key in val.keys():
            pathlib.Path(f'./example/{key}/{inner_key}').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

---

```
$ tree example
example
├── 1
│   ├── age
│   ├── name
│   └── sex
└── 2
    ├── age
    ├── name
    └── sex
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a string listing of the directories, you can try this:

```
s = {1: {'name': 'John', 'age': '27', 'sex': 'Male'},
      2: {'name': 'Marie', 'age': '22', 'sex': 'Female'}}
directories = [["{}/{}".format(a, c) for c in b.keys()] for a, b in s.items()]
```

Output:

```
[['1/age', '1/name', '1/sex'], ['2/age', '2/name', '2/sex']]
```